# WP7 Tombstoning - Easy practice

Tags: windows-phone-7, tombstoning

I have a databound xml reader. MainPage is connected to DetailsPage: When user clicks on the name in Main Page, She gets the details of this name (Age, Gender, Date of Birth etc.) in the DetailsPage.

I am in trouble with tombstoning atm. When I click on windows button, then click on back button I get into an empty DetailsPage.

What would be the easiest way to solve this problem? I tried to use TombstoneHelper but it also shows empty page.

DetailsPage.xaml

```
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="" Margin="0,0,0,80">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="432" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Margin="0,0,0,10" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" Foreground="#DEFFFFFF"><Run Text="Personal D"/><Run Text="e"/><Run Text="tails"/></TextBlock>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="432" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="20,0,7,0" Foreground="#DEFFFFFF"><Run Text="Name"/><Run Text=":"/></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="username" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="#DEFFFFFF" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="432" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="20,0,7,0" Foreground="#DEFFFFFF"><Run Text="Age"/><Run Text=":"/></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="age" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Age}" Foreground="#DEFFFFFF"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="432" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="20,0,7,0" Foreground="#DEFFFFFF"><Run Text="Nationality"/><Run Text=":"/></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="country" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Country}" Foreground="#DEFFFFFF"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="432" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="20,0,7,0" Foreground="#DEFFFFFF"><Run Text="Country of Birth"/><Run Text=":"/></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="cobirth" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Cobirth}" Foreground="#DEFFFFFF"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="432" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="20,0,7,0" Foreground="#DEFFFFFF"><Run Text="Place of Birth"/><Run Text=":"/></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="fobirth" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Pobirth}" Foreground="#DEFFFFFF"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

DetailsPage.cs

using TombstoneHelper;

```
    public User()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Portrait;
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

        this.SaveState();  // <- first line
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        this.RestoreState();  // <- second line
    }
```

Mainpage.Cs

```
    private void UserListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DetailsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

            FrameworkElement root = Application.Current.RootVisual as FrameworkElement;
            root.DataContext = (RosterItem)e.AddedItems[0];
            ((ListBox)sender).SelectedIndex = -1;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All things being equal Tombstone helper *should* just work.  Remember that you need to have named your controls (with an x:Name attribute) for Tombstone helper to access them.  Also make sure you are calling SaveState() in your NavigatedFrom() method and RestoreState() in NavigatedTo() (and not the other way round).

If that doesn't something must be wrong elsewhere in your code. We might be able to help if you post the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: I use Name attribute but it still doesn't work. I have added the ...From(e);this.SaveState(); ...
...To(e); this.RestoreState()... Codes into the DetailsPage only, do I have to add them to MainPage also?

Another possbility for the problem is; I have details in an Scrollviewer, does it effect the results?

Comment: TombstoneHelper only manages the contents of TextBoxes, PasswordBoxes, CheckBoxes, RadioButtons, Sliders, ListBoxes and ScrollViewers by default. It is not working because you are displaying for values to TextBlocks, which are not handled automatically by TombstoneHelper.  You could either look into TombstoneHelper's extensiblity model to see how you can add support for TextBlocks otherwise you could display your data in TextBoxes instead.

Comment: Aiden, I don't know how to thank you :D. It works now. Thank you very much!